# Should you default to using classes in C++?

Tags: object-oriented, c++, object-oriented-design

I recently discovered the KISS and YAGNI principles which made me question my usage with classes because I use them constantly without really thinking about it and I realized my code could be much simpler without them, but at the same time there doesn't seem to be a reason not to use classes like even if you don't utilize its features you could in the future (if necessary) so like there doesn't seem to be any harm in not using them in the first place.

I created this gui class which is responsible for initializing and deinitializing the imgui library as well as calling any callbacks which are responsible for drawing a specific widget.

```
class GUI {
public:
    GUI(SDL_Window* window, SDL_GLContext context);
    ~GUI(); 
    void Draw(); // calls start(), loops through callbacks, calls end()
    void AddCallback(std::function<void()> callback);
private:
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> callbacks;
    void start();
    void end();
};
```

It doesn't really do anything special with classes though (someone did mention RAII so perhaps thats one downside?) so would it be better to do something like this instead.

```
namespace GUI {
    // Maybe put this into a struct?
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> callbacks;

    void init();
    void deinit();
    void draw();
    void start();
    void end();
    void addCallback();
}
```

I guess what I'm trying to ask is should I write code the like second snippet or should I
just stick to classes?

Comment: To be clear, you're asking about classes vs namespaces, right? I think the key difference here is that one solution has a global variable, which should probably have external linkage if declared in a header, but probably really shouldn't be in a header to start with because it could be internal to the compilation unit. Assuming that you actually want a global, which you probably don't, not least because of the fun that is C++ static initialization. You don't need classes to get encapsulation/modularity, but classes/RAII really help with ensuring a predictable application lifecycle.

Comment: The essence of this question is "When procedural programming is sufficient for me, should I use classes, either" - and the answer is the same, regardless if asked for PHP or for C++

Answer (score 4):

```
//Maybe put this into a struct?
```

My c++ professor had a saying about this:

> The only difference between classes and structs is classes default to private.

So, sure. If you'd rather not have to type `public:` go ahead. Just understand, the weirder you make your code the fewer people will find it easy to read.

If what you really mean is you want to just make everything public you're flirting with destroying encapsulation.

Now sure, languages like python get along fine without a `private` keyword. But instead they have a convention. They mark fields that should be considered private with a leading underscore `_`.

Encapsulation really comes down to clearly signaling the difference between the front door and the employees only door. If you don't feel the need to lock it that's up to you.

> [...] the KISS and YAGNI principles [...] made me question my usage with classes because I use them constantly *without really thinking* about it and I realized my code could be much simpler without them

Sometimes Object Oriented Programming is a victim of it's own success. Just because it's popular doesn't mean you should use it for everything. You are right to be questioning anything you use without thinking. Programming should never be mindless ceremony. KISS and YAGNI demand that at least you be able to justify your choices.

C++ is a wide language. Classes are a big selling point for it over C but C++ can do more than classes. So don't feel like you must use classes just because you're in C++.

The best argument for going for classes/structs even when a procedural approach could have solved the problem is when they make it easier to read. I like breaking code into bite sized chunks that let me see one clear idea on one page while hiding other ideas from other chunks of code behind simple abstractions.

That might diagram like this:

[image]

With enough dots a) becomes preferable to b). Which means ya need some kinda box to put `em in with some kind of abstraction.

Figure out how to do that for me, even without classes/structs, and I'm all for it. If you can't give me that then I can only hope whatever problem you're solving is small and unlikely to grow.

Comment: I think the OP was not talking about classes vs structs, they were talking about classes vs. functions outside of classes.

Comment: @DocBrown from the second listing: "//Maybe put this into a struct?"

Comment: Sounds more like "do I really need to switch to classes/structs, or should I stay with this procedural style"?

Comment: @DocBrown better now?